# mysqli results from select query used in update query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having problems with only being able to have one result set from mysqli open at once. 
In particular I am trying to loop through a select query and update columns within that query after performing an action.

```
$db = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass , $DBName);
$sql = 'SELECT UPRN, POSTCODE FROM T_TEMP';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt -> Execute();

<Create an array from the above select statement as i understand that mysqli can 
only hold one result set at once (seems odd). I am unsure how to do this such that
i can then reference UPRN and POSTCODE later>

$stmt->Close();

$sql = 'update T_TEMP set LAT = ?, LONG = ? where UPRN = ?';
$stmt = $db ->prepare($sql);  

<loop through that array built above grabbing UPRN and POSTCODE as you go through>

$postcode = urlencode(<Reference the postcode in the array>);
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$postcode."&sensor=false"; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

$lat = round(floatval($xml->result->geometry->location->lat),4);
$long = round(floatval($xml->result->geometry->location->lng),4);

$stmt -> bind_param('ddi',$lat,$long,$UPRN);

$stmt -> Execute();

<end loop>
```

I am struggling with getting the results of the first query into an array and then referencing that array within the loop so i can set the values. 
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: show us your array... that will go a long way to help.

Comment: I don't have the array,  I know I need to build one but am unsure how to go about it. I will edit the code to make it more obvious what i am stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use mysqli. Use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) instead. In this latter case this desired code would be of one single line:

```
include 'db.php';
$sql  = 'SELECT UPRN, POSTCODE FROM T_TEMP';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(); // here you are
```

Comment: Although this question is irrelevant to my answer, I could answer to this one too. Using prepare() should be a habit. Or rather a reflex. prepare allows you to use prepared statements which always have to be used.

Comment: Ah so i now have:
   `$AddressArray = array();
    $AddressArray = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($ArrayAddressSingle as $AddressArray){

    }`

How do i address those columns within the loop?

Answer (score -1):

After being steered in the right direction i ended reading the result set into an array and then looping through that array. (This comment has been down voted but i am editing it to make it easier for someone else to find).

You cannot have two mysqli queries open as the server will only let you hold one in memory (actually on the server). So you read the first query into a php array and then loop through doing mysqli statements within that array.

```
$vInteger =1; //This is just an example variable

$sql ='select column from table where column = ?'; //select with a passed value

$stmt = db->prepare($sql);

$stmt-> bind_param('i', $vInteger); //again, this could be a string, double or integer

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result(); //retrieves the results from the server into a class

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc(){
   $Array[] = $row; //reads the rows into a new array
} 

$stmt -> free_result(); //Drop the mysqli bit cause you are going to need it again! :)

foreach($Array as $item){
  $item['Column']; // this is the column name from your original query


 // Of course in here you might want to do another mysqli query with the prepare etc etc and reference the $item.

 }
```

If you are determined to use mysqli that has worked for me and i think that the get_result creates a mysqli result class to which you can apply the fetch_assoc method..